# Does Kish Island allow Israelis?

Tags: visas, iran, israeli-citizens

Today I found out about Kish Island, which has different visa policies to mainland Iran. Do these differences extend to allowing Israelis, who aren't otherwise allowed into Iran?

Answer (score 10):

As an Israeli passport holder, it seems you cannot visit Kish.

The first being practical, [flying](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/London/K%C4%ABsh) [into](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kish_Island#By_plane) [Kish](http://en.kishairlines.ir/flight-destinations/International/2/view/) you will either layover in Iran somewhere (which entry you will be [refused](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Iran#Get_in)) or through the UAE (which entry you will also be [refused](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates#Get_in)).

The second being that while Kish itself has a visa free policy, it's still part of Iran proper which has a [entry](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IL&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KIH&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) [ban](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/iran/entry-requirements) on any passport bearing an Israeli stamp or connection with Israel.

Comment: My understanding is that Israeli passport holders generally do not have trouble transiting through UAE airports

Answer (score 5):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Iran#Israel):

> Admission is ***refused*** to holders of passports or travel documents
>   containing a visa/stamp for **Israel** or any data that passenger has been
>   to Israel or indication of any connection with the State of Israel.

It also says:

> *All tourists may stay in Kish Island for 14 days or less without
>   obtaining any visa.* [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Iran)

But that is for tourists and people already in the country (Iran) who have obtained the visa. But since Kish is already in Iran, an Israeli passport holder cannot visit the place.